# How to sort json based on date with jq?

Tags: json, sorting, datetime, jq

How can I sort this json output based on the "lastModified" value? I've tried on looking at other topics, but can't make it work with jq. This example is just one entry of many.

I've tried `jq -s '.[].items |= sort_by(.lastModified)'` but that's not working.

Each item in .items array should be sorted by date based on the "lastModified" value, so that in the output they would be listed from oldest to newest.

```
[
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "Y29tbW9KJHDGGViZjdihjdfgJDHF72Q2NNlNTE4MQ",
      "repository": "files",
      "format": "raw",
      "group": "/artifactory",
      "name": "artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-cpp-ce-7.68.14.rpm",
      "version": null,
      "assets": [
        {
          "downloadUrl": "https://nexusrepo.com/repository/files/artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-cpp-ce-7.68.14.rpm",
          "path": "artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-cpp-ce-7.68.14.rpm",
          "id": "MKUKYTGkNTEFYGidfUDFWQ4Mw",
          "repository": "files",
          "format": "raw",
          "checksum": {
            "sha1": "f7ff96bc6c0cc6ca6163a61635b",
            "sha256": "97c152220522a2b91032f3a884313a88431a4371a4ef22e2e517cb3b",
            "sha512": "52d225b9d3a35ef800b556e20067452c7b225b9d3a35ef80066173850c24bd4",
            "md5": "63044d747d7e5b0c59436"
          },
          "contentType": "application/x-rpm",
          "lastModified": "2023-10-18T12:59:48.331+00:00",
          "lastDownloaded": "2023-10-26T09:34:14.859+00:00",
          "uploader": "user",
          "uploaderIp": "10.30.55.12",
          "fileSize": 1273649726,
          "blobCreated": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "continuationToken": null
}
```

]

Comment: Which array do want to sort, the top-level array, or its items' `.items` arrays, or *their* items' `.assets` arrays (where `.lastModified` is actually located), or a specific combination of them? Please provide your expected output for the sample given. Also, please explicate what is "not working".

Comment: I added more explanation, hope it clarifies a bit.

Comment: It does not, unfortunately. You've only added the sentence `items array should be sorted by date based on the "lastModified" value`, but the `.items` array itself does not contain a `.lastModified` value; it is located deeper, and occurs (potentially) multiple times. You'd need to explain, for example, how to aggregate them.

Comment: Right, so each item has assets array where the "lastModified" is and basically I need the assets sections or whole items to be sorted by date in the output.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Example: The `.items` array has two items. The first one has 3 items in its `.assets` array, including the dates (substituted with letters for the sake of simplicity) D, F and B. The second one also has 3 items in its `.assets` array, containing the dates E, A and C. Which of the two items in the `.items` array should come first, and why?

Answer (score 0):

This worked out:

```
jq -s '.[0].items |= sort_by(.assets[0].lastModified) | .[0].items'
```

Comment: First, `.[0].items |= … | .[0].items` can be simplified to `.[0].items | …` (turning the update into a pipe, and omitting the second traversal). Second, using `-s` in combination with `.[0].items` does not match up with the sample input (which is `[{"items": …}]`), as `-s` adds another array. Third, if this "worked out", then the answer to my [question about aggregation from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77366770/how-to-sort-json-based-on-date-with-jq?noredirect=1#comment136392247_77366770) was using **the first date** from the `.assets` array (namely `.assets[0]`).